# Good books for 4th graders focusing on fun, interesting and challenging math topics and exercises

Tags: reference-request, education

My son shows strong interests in math and he is currently a 4th grader. I wonder if there are any good books that could be used to keep up his interests and at the same time challenge him a little bit.

Comment: What sort of math is he doing right now?  What's really capturing his interests?

Comment: Is he doing 4th-grade math, or is he ahead of his grade level? Martin Gardner's books might be good. Non-book options might include math competitions or playing with free software such as Geogebra.

Comment: He is ahead of his grade level. He likes to solve the puzzles and logic problems

Comment: Also: Mathematical Puzzles of Sam Loyd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try *The Number Devil: A Mathematical Adventure* ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805062998)), although it's more "fun" then "exercises". (I'm glad you included "fun" and "interesting" in your question; nothing better to destroy someone's interest in math than a bunch of "exercises".) That's the only one I can think of that's written for children right now. But depending on how much of a reader he is, you might consider the "pop math" stuff written for adult audiences. Look up "recreational mathematics"; try Martin Gardner or Ian Stewart perhaps. If he's up to it, take him to the 510s of the adult nonfiction section of a public library (and the rest of it too!). I certainly had a lot of fun there in elementary and middle school.

He might enjoy competitions and summer camps (especially in a couple of years), which have the additional benefit of providing a community of peers. If you're in the U.S., you might look into MATHCOUNTS, Art of Problem Solving (books, online classes, videos, and forum), MOEMS, Khan Academy, CTY, and MathPath. I've only had (very positive) firsthand experiences with the first two, but people have recommended the others.

Comment: Wow, this is so nice set of books. And yes, I want to keep up his interests to make it more of fun experience. Thanks a lot!